# RegEx expression to find a href links and add NoFollow to them

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a RegEx rule to find all a href HTML links on my webpage and add a 'rel="nofollow"' to them.

However, I have a list of URLs that must be excluded (for exmaple, ANY (wildcards) internal link (eg. pokerdiy.com) - so that any internal link that has my domain name in is excluded from this. I want to be able to specify exact URLs in the exclude list too - for example - http://www.example.com/link.aspx)

Here is what I have so far which is not working:

(]+)(href="http://.*?(?!(pokerdiy))[^>]+>)

If you need more background/info you can see the full thread and requirements here (skip the top part to get to the meat):
http://www.snapsis.com/Support/tabid/601/aff/9/aft/13117/afv/topic/afpgj/1/Default.aspx#14737

Comment: Don't. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: DOES NOT COMPUTE! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Ok, I have read the attached and get the point. However, my requirements are limited and parsing with RegEx IS my only option. I appreciate the following:
    * It's generally a bad idea.
    
(from Coding Horror).

So... with that in mind - can anyone help with my RegEx code please? I can explain why I am limited to regex parsing later, but I need a solution please, no matter how much of a bad idea it may seem.

Comment: This doesnt really apply here the href parameter is simple enough to be parsed by a regex especially when its a limited subset of all possible hrefs i.e. only the hrefs in your pages!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(<a href="https?://)((?:(?!\b(pokerdiy.com|www\.example\.com/link\.aspx)\b)[^"])+)"
```

would match the first part of any link that starts with `http://` or `https://` and doesn't contain `pokerdiy.com` or `www.example.com/link.aspx` anywhere in the `href` attribute. Replace that by

```
\1\2" rel="nofollow"
```

If a `rel="nofollow"` is already present, you'll end up with two of these. And of course, relative links or other protocols like `ftp://` etc. won't be matched at all.

Explanation:

`(?!\b(foo|bar)\b)[^"]` matches any non-`"` character unless it it possible to match `foo` or `bar` at the current location. The `\b`s are there to make sure we don't accidentally trigger on `rebar` or `foonly`.

This whole contruct is repeated (`(?: ... )+`), and whatever is matched is preserved in backreference `\2`.

Since the next token to be matched is a `"`, the entire regex fails if the attribute contains `foo` or `bar` anywhere.

Comment: Tim: The quality and helpfulness of this community never fails to amaze me - thank you so much for the indepth answer! 

There is one little problem - if the a link has a title tag (or anthing else) - between the a and the href then this expression fails - eg. a target="_blank" href="http://www.casinogamblingweb.com"  would not be matched. Can you please help me make it so that anything can be between the a and the href?

Also - I understand the potential duplicate nofollow tag. Is there anyway to have the expression check if it already has a nofollow tag anywhere in it?

Thanks!!

Comment: Please check this: 
(<a[^>]+)(href="https?://)((?:(?!\b(pokerdiy.com|www\.example\.com/link\.aspx)\b)[^"])+)"
and
$1$2$3" rel="nofollow"

Comment: That should work and is exactly what I would have suggested myself.

Answer (score 10):

An improvement to James' regex:

```
(<a\s*(?!.*\brel=)[^>]*)(href="https?://)((?!(?:(?:www\.)?'.implode('|(?:www\.)?', $follow_list).'))[^"]+)"((?!.*\brel=)[^>]*)(?:[^>]*)>
```

This regex will matches links NOT in the string array $follow_list. The strings don't need a leading 'www'. :)
The advantage is that this regex will preserve other arguments in the  tag (like target, style, title...). If a `rel` argument already exists in the  tag, the regex will NOT match, so you can force follows on urls not in $follow_list

Replace the with:

```
$1$2$3"$4 rel="nofollow">
```

Full example (PHP):

```
function dont_follow_links( $html ) {
 // follow these websites only!
 $follow_list = array(
  'google.com',
  'mypage.com',
  'otherpage.com',
 );
 return preg_replace(
  '%(<a\s*(?!.*\brel=)[^>]*)(href="https?://)((?!(?:(?:www\.)?'.implode('|(?:www\.)?', $follow_list).'))[^"]+)"((?!.*\brel=)[^>]*)(?:[^>]*)>%',
  '$1$2$3"$4 rel="nofollow">',
  $html);
}
```

If you want to overwrite `rel` no matter what, I would use a `preg_replace_callback` approach where in the callback the rel attribute is replaced separately:

```
$subject = preg_replace_callback('%(<a\s*[^>]*href="https?://(?:(?!(?:(?:www\.)?'.implode('|(?:www\.)?', $follow_list).'))[^"]+)"[^>]*)>%', function($m) {
    return preg_replace('%\srel\s*=\s*(["\'])(?:(?!\1).)*\1(\s|$)%', ' ', $m[1]).' rel="nofollow">';
}, $subject);
```

Comment: @para what if i want to prevent user from adding his own `rel` attribute? i need to prevent following links that are not listed in `$follow_list`

Comment: @alex i would probably go for a preg_replace_callback approach as the easiest solution. i updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 6):

I've developed a slightly more robust version that can detect whether the anchor tag already has "rel=" in it, therefore not duplicating attributes.

```
(<a\s*(?!.*\brel=)[^>]*)(href="https?://)((?!blog.bandit.co.nz)[^"]+)"([^>]*)>
```

Matches

```
<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
<a title="Google" href="http://google.com">Google</a>
<a target="_blank" href="http://google.com">Google</a>
<a href="http://google.com" title="Google" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

But doesn't match

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="http://google.com">Google</a>
<a href="http://google.com" rel="nofollow">Google</a>
<a href="http://google.com" rel="nofollow" title="Google" target="_blank">Google</a>
<a href="http://google.com" title="Google" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Google</a>
<a href="http://google.com" title="Google" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Google</a>
<a target="_blank" href="http://blog.bandit.co.nz">Bandit</a>
```

Replace using

```
$1$2$3"$4 rel="nofollow">
```

Hope this helps someone!

James