# Multiple rel attributes

Tags: html, seo, rel, nofollow

How would Google behave if encounter with a link having two different `rel` attribute?

```
<a href="example.com" rel="follow" rel="nofollow">hello</a>
```

I'm trying to purge content user insert into DB. I need to prevent user from making links as follow for search engines, but I'm not going to do it for internal links so I can't use meta in header to prevent all links from following. So if a user has added `rel` attribute manually I would have the new link with two `rel` like above example. I use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2452743/4061644) for making my regex.

Comment: This situation probably is not defined. Simple reason is that it is obviously impossible to have two attributes with the same name in a single element. Therefore it is up to the implementation how it behaves.

Comment: Does Google document anywhere that they would recognize the `follow` link type (which is invalid in HTML5)?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot have more than one `rel` attribute into one element, but you can insert more than one argument into a single rel attribute value - just delimit them with a space:

**Valid:** `<a href="example.com" rel="follow nofollow">hello</a>`

**Not Valid:** `<a href="example.com" rel="follow" rel="nofollow">hello</a>`

I think for what you are looking for :

> GoogleBot does obey the `rel="nofollow"` attribute.. as for `rel="follow"` - I don't think so. `rel="follow"` is only used to override the **default** **"nofollow"**

It actually depends on what you want to achieve, If you want "nofollow" then just use `rel="nofollow"` & the `rel="follow"` is not needed, But on the other hand if you want `rel="follow"`, then you need to provide `rel="nofollow"` first and then override it by `rel="follow"` like below

```
<a href="example.com" rel="nofollow follow">hello</a>
```

[Here](https://moz.com/community/q/rel-follow-what-the-does-that-mean) is a good article which explains it

Comment: and how would google treat with your first link? follow or not?

Comment: It would actually do both, "follow" first & then "nofollow"

Comment: Is `rel="follow"` even valid? I can't find it mentioned anywhere